# Topological K-theory references

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, book-recommendation, topological-k-theory

I am interesting in learning about (topological) K-theory. As far as I can see there are 3 main references used:

1) [Atiyah's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006BS0N2):  This looks to be very readable and requires minimal pre-requesities. However, the big downside is there are no exercises

2) [Allan Hatcher's online notes](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VBpage.html): If his Algebraic Topology book is any guide, this should be an excellent readable account of K-theory. I note that this is unfinished however.

3) [Karoubi's Book](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=fJzlLkHBYTYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=karoubi+k+theory&source=bl&ots=s9z46Q7arJ&sig=33NeRaK928x10oTtA6kL9AaI4_M&hl=en&ei=EUmxTYCQL5S-sAOS44HpCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false): A nice looking book - perhaps less readable than Atiyah? (personal opinion, based on a quick scan)

Are there any other references/on-line notes available? I am probably leaning towards an Atiyah/Hatcher combination.

(Can this be made community-wiki?)

Comment: There's also Segal's paper "Equivariant K-Theory" if you want your K-Theory to have a $G$ action.  He runs through some of the basics.

Comment: *swoosh*- **wham**. Yes it can. (Wiki-hammered)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"[Complex Topological K-Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521856345)" by Efton Park is a pretty decent introduction to topological K-Theory, but I'd actually go with Karoubi's book.

There is also a chapter on K-Theory in John Peter May's "[A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf)", which is in my opinion the best text on algebraic topology currently available, including some references and recommended further reading.

Comment: That chapter of May is really cool!

Comment: All of May is really cool :D

Comment: Good point! I like that book a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the references. I'd love to be able to digest all of May's book, but it is very heavy for a first read! I'll have a look further at Karoubi

Comment: @Qwirk: It is indeed very heavy, but also very rewarding. A good strategy would be to take May's book as a guideline and complement with easier literature once you feel stuck or unable to fill in the details.