# Good books on Topological K theory

Tags: book-recommendation, k-theory

I recently read a book on K theory of C* algebras by Rordam, Lausten. Now I want to read the subject of Topological K theory. Can someone suggest me a good book on this subject. As I am a mathematics student I would like to read a Math flavoured book, and not a Physics flavoured one as the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2160577/video-lectures-on-topological-k-theory) question suggests.

The only book that I know on this subject is the one by Atiyah. I don't mean to disrespect the book but I feel it is very old. Are there other good books. It would also be nice if someone gave me an idea of how this branch links to some other interesting branches of Mathematics. I mean to ask how does K theory interact with other branches of Mathematics. I know I am being a bit vague, but even some rough idea will be very useful.

Comment: You can look for some ideas in this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34486/topological-k-theory-references?rq=1

Comment: @MarvinF, Thanks a lot.